# Android - Maximum Timeout for InetAddress isReachable()

Tags: java, android, timeout, ip

I'm using InetAddress.getByName(params[0]).isReachable(300000) to
determine if my NAS is alive.
By measuring the time before and after the above methode I found out
that the timeout has a maximum of about 3 min. 10 seconds, even if I
set the timeout to 600000 (about 10 minutes).

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a better way to implement such
function?

regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed my approach. Now I'm using Runtime.getRuntime().exec to execute a ping to the remote-ip. That's more reliable than isReachable.